# saving html input tag to django models

Tags: python, html, django

I have a form that contains input tags that are hidden, when i POST the form to the views and print, i see the values i need but the content is not saving to the database
here is my html

```
<form method="POST" action="/selly/cart/" item_id="{{product.pk}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1 name="description">Description is : {{each_item.description}}</h1>
    <p><input type="hidden" name="description" value="{{each_item.description}}"></p>

    <span name="price">Price is : $ {{each_item.price}}/piece</span>
    <p><input type="hidden" name="price" value ="{{each_item.price}}"></p>

    <p>Quantity is : <input type="number" default="0" name="quantity"> piece ( {{each_item.item_remaining}} pieces available )</p>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add to Cart">

</form>
```

here is my views.py

```
from selly.models import Cart
def cart(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print "rp ", request.POST

        description = request.POST['description']
        print "Description is ", description

        price = request.POST['price']
        print "Price is ", price

        quantity = request.POST['quantity']
        print "Quantity is ", quantity

        items =  Cart.objects.get_or_create(client="client", description="description", price="price", quantity="quantity")
        print "ITEMS", items
    return render(request, 'selly/cart.html', {'items': items})
```

Here is the model.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    def total(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

Is there a way of making it save to the database i created called Cart

Comment: Just call save method: `items.save()`

Comment: @Selcuk am getting [u"'price' value must be a decimal number."] as error

Comment: What price value are you entering?

Comment: He's assigning it as a string, see my answer.

Comment: not entering any value for price, if you see it it is in hidden input field. The only input field that is visible is quantity

Comment: If the answer below is helpful, it'd be great if you could accept it please.  If it isn't helpful, let me know what the problem you're still having is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you're not getting an error with that code - get_or_create returns a tuple, per the docs:

> Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the retrieved or
>   created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new
>   object was created.

So your line `items =  Cart.objects.get_or_create(client="client", description="description", price="price", quantity="quantity")`

needs to be

`items, created = =  Cart.objects.get_or_create(client="client", description="description", price="price", quantity="quantity")`

You'll also be able to interrogate that created variable, because if it's false, then it hasn't created a new object; if it hasn't created a new object, then all get_or_create is doing is returning the object already in the database.

You need to save the object manually if you're updating it.

This is because:

> This is meant as a shortcut to boilerplatish code. For example:

```
try:
    obj = Person.objects.get(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon') 
except Person.DoesNotExist:
    obj = Person(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon', birthday=date(1940, 10, 9))
    obj.save()
```

Full details are on the docs page [for get_or_create.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Also, your last line is wrong - you're assigning strings to the object, where you do `price="price"` - you actually want to do `price=price`, because you're assigning o`bject.price=price`, which is what you called the variable in the code above.  I'd suggest maybe calling those variables 'incoming_price' or similar to avoid shadowing/confusion.